# Update method - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity')

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-core

I have a problem that I cannot solve.
When Im trying to update one field in the db called 'Introduction', I get this message from API:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity')
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)
at ClinicAPIv1.Data.UserRepository.Update(ClinicUser clinicUser) in E:\Users\User\Desktop\Clinic\ClinicAPIv1\ClinicAPIv1\Data\UserRepository.cs:line 61
at ClinicAPIv1.Controllers.UsersController.UpdateDoctor(DoctorUpdateDTO doctorUpdateDTO) in E:\Users\User\Desktop\Clinic\ClinicAPIv1\ClinicAPIv1\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 74
at lambda_method34(Closure , Object )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at ClinicAPIv1.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in E:\Users\User\Desktop\Clinic\ClinicAPIv1\ClinicAPIv1\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 30

I understand that the problem is with the update function in my repository:

```
public void Update(ClinicUser clinicUser)
    {
        _context.Entry(clinicUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

line 61 is

```
_context.Entry(clinicUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Controller Put method looks like:

```
   [HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDoctor(DoctorUpdateDTO doctorUpdateDTO)
    {
        var email = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByEmail(email);

        _mapper.Map(doctorUpdateDTO, user);

        _userRepository.Update(user);

        if (await _userRepository.SaveAllAsync()) return NoContent();

        return BadRequest("Failed to update Doctor Profile :(");
    }
```

Line 74 is

```
_userRepository.Update(user);
```

DoctorUpdateDTO:

```
public class DoctorUpdateDTO
{
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<ClinicUser, MemberDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt => opt.MapFrom(
                src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault().Url));
        CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDTO>();
        CreateMap<DoctorUpdateDTO, ClinicUser>();
    }
}
```

GetUserByEmail:

```
public async Task<ClinicUser> GetUserByEmail(string email)
    {
        return await _context.clinicUsers
            .Where(x => x.TemporaryRole == "Doctor")
            .Include(p => p.Photos)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == email);
    }
```

ClinicUser:

```
public class ClinicUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Specialization { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public string TemporaryRole { get; set; }
}
```

**Please help me solve the problem**

Comment: So. When you debugged this, at which point was the object state not what you expected?

Comment: You should try to include unit tests in your code. solves these problems a lot. In anyway, check the EntityState.Modified to see if it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Chain ReverseMap after CreateMap calls in your AutoMapperProfiles. Get more information [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html#reverse-mapping-and-unflattening).

Comment: I tried to use reverse mapping, but the error is the same :(

Comment: Can you please update your question with ClinicUser definition?

Comment: Done, its a class witch db fields

Comment: If you break at line _userRepository.Update(user) , does your user has updated Introduction value? Try to debug and see if mapping is properly done.

Comment: Thanks for help, I solved this thanks to you ;))))))